Why is Task Manager showing more than 100% CPU Usage? What does it mean?
I have a weird issue. This is the second time that I'm encountering this over the last 2-3 months.
My CPU Usage is constantly running between 120% and 200%... How? How is this possible? What does it mean if my CPU is showing more than 100%?

Also when I sort by CPU usage and look at the percentages, they don't even count up to 100%, let alone 199%. Same for RAM as well, I count around 40GB RAM which should put it around 60% usage, but it's almost 100% usage.
My CPU is: AMD Ryzen 7 8845HS

Hard to say, but CPU percentage numbers are rather complicated nowadays with CPU frequency scaling and efficiency/performance cores being taking into account. What’s your CPU? Have you checked the “Performance” view yet?

My CPU is: AMD Ryzen 7 8845HS. I haven't checked the Performance tab yet while it' over 100%. It's now back to normal again under 100%. again

Task Manager does not display every single process on the system only those running at the user level. Suspect this is a locale issue. What locale are you using for your system default?

@Ramhound My locale is "English (United Kingdom)"

You might compare with Microsoft's/Sysinternals' similar tool, Process Explorer, to see if it has more rational results on Win 11: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer . That would at least let you know if it's a Win 11 issue, or just Win 11's Task Manager.

@Ramhound Sorry. Right-click where exactly?
